# White screen when I run app on flutter emulator?

Tags: flutter, dart, emulation

I have a problem when I run my app on flutter via the android emulator. It's just a white screen and i cannot interact with my app at all. I shared the main.dart, homepage.dart for your consideration. Thank you

edit: now it's a black screen
edit 2: [stuck like this for the past 10 mins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Thqp.png)

**This is the main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/widgets/stock_management.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('You have pressed the button this many times:',),
            Text('$counter', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  counter++;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Increment'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**this is the home_page.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My Home Page'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Welcome to my home page!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Share your code as a text instead of the images

Comment: I've just added it.

Comment: can you add the logs from the debug console tab ?

Answer (score 0):

I think with the counter function, you should define the HomePage as a Stateful Widget because every time you press the increment button, you're updating the state for the counter value being passed through.

Try for your main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

And for your home_page.dart file, try:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('You have pressed the button this many times:',),
            Text('$counter', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  counter++;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Increment'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Not too sure about what's going on with the blank white/black screen you're getting from the emulator. You could try to screenshot it with some more details about your dev environment and someone should be able to help you out.